# MySQL Down, Magento throws error on index with MySql Password etc

Tags: magento-1.7, error

I was just monitoring my magento website, and all of a sudden mysql went down for few seconds and Magento throw an error visible for everyone on the homepage / index. This error contained the MySql Password & User ID... If somebody else is monitoring the website as I did, they for sure now know the password of MySql...

How can I disable Magento from outputting any kind of errors on the frontend?!?!

here's the error (those in red are the password and id)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbRhg.jpg

Comment: If you "fixed" the "Error Processing Request" screen to show errors instead of writing them to a file, go unfix it... It's not supposed to be used in a production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure developer mode isn't enabled, and disable error display:

`ini_set('display_errors', 0);`

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/index.php#L69-L73

Comment: Thank you! Yep, it was set to 1. I've changed it to 0... hope this hides the errors on frontend because it's frustrating to see your DB password outputted like that.

Comment: Don't run Magento on production in Developer Mode!

Comment: it just did it again...

Comment: Your host may not allow `ini_set` a `phpinfo();` after your ini_set in `index.php` can determine if its in the disable_functions list.  I'd also be quick to save it, load the page, and comment out the `phpinfo()` so others won't see it but may help shed light on the current php.ini settings of your host.

Comment: I've just tried and this was the msg by magento:

There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 592149129780

Answer (score 1):

If it was my server I would turn off error messages and have them fail with no output to the customer.
To do this depends on your server and configuration, but hopefully your hosting company can help if you do not have ssh access to it.
This is one method you can try if you just want to do some testing
On the index.php add this
error_reporting(0);

That should hide all error messages.

Comment: It appears Boomer beat me to the answer, nicely done sir.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, Russell. I'm definitely going to ask them in the matter and see.

Comment: @RussellAlbin Have an up vote, happy holidays! ;)

Comment: Woo hoo! Thanks boomer. If you have any magento questions let me know. I am trying to share my knowledge. Been using stack exchange for years and now it's time to pay back.

Comment: I meant to add that your have proven yourself pretty knowledgeable in Magento so you probably won't need me!  Have a great day.